# How do you figure out a mechanical trap's craft cost?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, crafting, traps

I was curious about the cost of traps. The cost of a mechanical trap is 1,000 gp × the trap’s Challenge Rating. Is this the crafted cost, or the marketed price to hire someone to build the trap. Is the cost already a third or do I pay 1/3rd the materials' cost, as mentioned on wilderness traps (in quote following)?

> When in a trap’s associated terrain, instead of paying 1/3 the item’s price in raw materials, the trap maker can attempt a Survival check against the Craft DC of the trap.

Comment: Hi BroStuff, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange! Check out our [tour] to see how we work here, and when you reach 20 rep, you'll be able to join us in [chat].

Answer (score 5):

### Mechanical Trap Cost

The cost to buy [mechanical traps](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/traps-hazards-and-special-terrains/traps#TOC-Mechanical-Trap-Cost) is between 250 gp *x* Challenge Rating to 1,000 gp *x* Challenge Rating of the trap, depending on the complexity of the trap (at GM discretion):

> The cost of a mechanical trap is **1,000 gp × the trap’s Challenge Rating**. If the trap uses spells in its trigger or reset, add those costs separately. If the trap cannot be reset, divide the cost in half. If the trap has an automatic reset, increase the cost by half (+50%). Particularly simple traps, such as pit traps, might have a greatly reduced cost, subject to GM discretion. Such traps might cost as little as **250 gp × the trap’s Challenge Rating**.
>
> After you’ve determined the cost by Challenge Rating, add the price of any alchemical items or poison you incorporated into the trap. If the trap uses one of these elements and has an automatic reset, multiply the poison or alchemical item cost by 20 to provide an adequate supply of doses.

### Crafting Traps

This is not the cost to **craft** one, as that is covered by the [Craft Skill](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/craft) rules, as described under [Craft DC for Mechanical Traps](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/traps-hazards-and-special-terrains/traps#TOC-Craft-DCs-for-Mechanical-Traps):

> Once you know the Challenge Rating of a trap, determine the **Craft (traps)** Dc by referring to the values and modifiers given on Table: Craft Traps DCs.
>
> Making the Checks: To determine how much **progress** a character makes on building a trap each **week**, that character makes a Craft (traps) check. See the Craft skill description for details on Craft checks and the circumstances that can affect them.

This means that the crafting process follows the same rules under the [Craft Skill](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/craft), and it takes 1/3 of the market price in *raw materials* to craft the trap you want:

> **Pay 1/3 of the item’s price** for the raw material cost.
>
> Make an appropriate Craft check representing **one week’s worth of work**.

To figure out the DC, however, it is given a table based on the Challenge Rating of the trap:

[image: Craft Trap DC]

Which means, that according to this [craft calculator for 3.5/Pathfinder](http://viajon.net/pf/crafting/), a CR 1 trap **would take around 8 weeks** to be crafted (12% progress per week), which is *lame*, but are the rules we got. So, as a fellow GM, i would suggest to change the rules around to allow additional workers to reduce the time required proportionally, so it doesnt sound inviable for a character to bother crafting things.

### Repairing Traps

The cost to repair a trap is 1/5 of of the cost to craft one (which is also described on the [Craft Skill](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/craft) rules), so 200 gp *x* CR.

> The cost for raw materials is one-fifth of the trap’s original market price.